# Distribution of $X$, when distribution of $\ln(X/X_0)$ is normal?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

We assume that $\ln{(S_T/S_0)} \sim N(\mu T, \sigma^2 T)$. I have in suggested solution that
$$\ln(S_T/S_0) = \mu T + \sigma \sqrt{T} Z$$
where $Z \sim N(0,1)$ or $S_T = S_0e^{\mu T + \sigma \sqrt{T}Z}$. How do we know that $\ln{(S_T/S_0)} = \mu T + \sigma \sqrt{T}Z$? Also, when $S_T$ is lognormally distributed as here, we have

$$E[S_T^\alpha] = E\left[(S_0e^{\mu T + \sigma \sqrt{T}Z})^\alpha\right] = S_0^\alpha E\left[e^{\alpha \mu T + \alpha σ \sqrt{T}Z}\right] = S_0^\alpha e^{\alpha \mu T + \alpha^2 \sigma^2 T/2}$$

How did $E\left[e^{\alpha \mu T + \alpha σ\sqrt{T}Z}\right] = e^{\alpha \mu T + \alpha^2 \sigma^2 T/2}$ ?

Comment: For your first question, set $Z = (\ln(S_T/S_0) - \mu T)/(\sigma \sqrt{T})$ and show that $Z \sim N(0,1)$. For your second question, you need a formula for $E(e^{a + bZ}) = e^a E(e^{bZ})$ which is essentially the moment generating function of a standard normal r.v. evaluated at $b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally if $X \sim N(μ, σ)$ then $$Z=\frac{X-μ}{σ}\sim N(0,1)$$ Consequently here (with $\ln{(S_T/S_0)}$ in place of $X$) $$Z=\frac{\ln{(S_T/S_0)-μΤ}}{σ\sqrt{T}}\sim N(0,1)$$ Making the right (elementary) transformations yields the first relations. Now, the expectation is calculated as follows 
$$E[S_T^\alpha] = S_0^\alpha e^{\alpha \mu T}E\left[e^{\alpha σ \sqrt{T}Z}\right]=S_0^\alpha e^{\alpha \mu T} MGF_Z(\alpha σ\sqrt{T})$$ where $MGF_Z$ denotes the moment generating function of $Z$. For the normal distribution $ N(μ,σ^2)$ the MGF is given by $$MGF(t)=e^{tμ+\frac12σ^2t^2}$$ and for the standard normal $Z\sim N(0,1)$ which you need here $$MGF_Z(t)=e^{\frac12t^2}$$ and the result follows by substituting $t=ασ\sqrt{T}$.

Comment: Could you evaluate how you get the $E[e \alpha \mu \sqrt{T} Z]$ because i get $E[e^{\alpha \mu \sqrt{T}Z}]$ and how do we know that this is $MGF_z(\mu \sqrt{T})$ and not $MGF_z(\alpha \mu \sqrt{T})$. Why is the MGF for $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and not the MGF for $N(0, 1)$?

Comment: My formula sheet says that the MGF for $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ is $e^{\mu t + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 t^2}$ wouldn't that make the MGF for $N(0,1)$ equal to $e^{0*t + \frac{1}{2}1^2 t^2} = e^{\frac{1}{2}t^2}$? Thanks a lot though, I'm getting a rough understanding of the explaination.

Also one more thing

Comment: The exercise is for portfolio theory class. $S_T$ is the price of a traded asset at time $T$. $S_T^\beta$ is the liability for the bank selling a derivative that gives the owner the amount. So the T is a time-variable.


Also one more thing $E[e^{\alpha \mu T + \alpha \mu \sqrt{T} Z}] = e^{\alpha \mu T}E[e^{\alpha \mu \sqrt{T}Z}]$. Does this require independence? how do we know we can move out the $e^{\alpha \mu T}$

Comment: Alright now everything works out fine.  Also one more thing 
$E[e^{\alpha \mu T + \alpha \mu \sqrt{T}Z}] = e^{ \alpha \mu T} E[e^{/alpha \mu \sqrt{T} Z}]$


 Does this require independence? Or is it fine to just move $e^{\alpha \mu T}$ out? Or maybe the $T$ is considered to be a constant and thus the whole expression is considered a constant? Thanks again!